# ElasticSearch: query for N items of each category

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index of goods in ElasticSearch (5.5), of them every product has a field "category", like "GLOVES", "COAT", "TOWEL".

With the `terms` query I can select items belonging to several categories, e.g.

```
{
    "terms": {
        "div_id": ["COAT", "DRESS", "JACKET"]
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that I want to have in response several items of each type, say, not less than 3 (given that total size of answer is 15 records).

And I have no clear idea how to do this. With the given "straight" way it may return any number from any category. The closest I get is to add random_score which makes result "diverse", but it then depends on how many percents every category takes in the index.

I suspect there should be different approach, but can't guess correct keywords, seemingly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try top hits agg documented [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html?q=top_hits#search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation).

Comment: But am I guaranteed to have at least, say, 5 in each category in agg results? Provided that I have much more than 5 in each category in the index, of course...

Comment: yes - as long as your query doesnt constrain the documents in which aggregations runs on. You can control agg size with size param

Comment: ah, so this "size" is not total size, but for every category? thanks, let me try this and I'll be back soon :)

Comment: Sorry , i think i misinterpreted your question. I somehow thought you were looking for document counts.. let me edit my answer , sorry about that

Comment: Thank you, the "top_hits" really works. Just works and it's what I need :)