# Get 10 best Results from ElasticSearch by domain

Tags: elasticsearch, request

I have five different Domains in ElasticSearch, which are indexed and should be used for a fulltext search.

If I do a GET request like

```
GET endpoint_to_my_elastic_search/*/_search?q=test
```

I get the result ordered by _score. So far so good, but I want to have a result which shows me the 10 best hits (by score) of every domain. I tried it this way:

```
GET endpoint_to_my_elastic_search/domain1/_search?q=test&size=10
GET endpoint_to_my_elastic_search/domain2/_search?q=test&size=10
GET endpoint_to_my_elastic_search/domain3/_search?q=test&size=10
GET endpoint_to_my_elastic_search/domain4/_search?q=test&size=10
GET endpoint_to_my_elastic_search/domain5/_search?q=test&size=10
```

Nice - it works. Now I have 10 best results from every domain. But the number of domains will increase in the future to 10 or 20. So I have to send 20 request to my ElasticSearch... smells like bad performance ;-)

Is there a way to tell ElasticSearch to give me best 10 Results from every requested Domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199512/elasticsearch-query-for-n-items-of-each-category/59200771#59200771) few days back - suggestion is to use [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggs..

Update: _index is a meta field, so you may be able to query across multiple indices using wildcard or an alias and use that field for agg:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/index-*/_search?pretty -d '
{
  "aggs": {
    "top_indices": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_index"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_docs": {
          "top_hits": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: :I found this page, too, but didn't find the right way to use it

Comment: Are each domains indexed as different indices ?

Comment: yes, correct... there are three different indicies.

Comment: Nirmal: field: _index was the right hint to find the answer to this question... now I've git the correct syntax for the "aggs". Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

With Nirmal's and Hariharan's help I got the right JSON, which shows me the 10 best results from all my domains:

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "top_tags": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "_index",
            },
            "aggs": {
                "top_search_hits": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "_score": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "size" : 10
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```