# Elasticsearch limit result like Google

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I'm having an issue finding the best approach to the following elastic search. I have data as below:

```
{product: "A", sellerID: "1"},
{product: "B", sellerID: "2"},
{product: "C", sellerID: "2"},
{product: "D", sellerID: “2”},
{product: "E", sellerID: “1"},
{product: "F", sellerID: "3"}
```

I'd like to be able to return the results:

```
{product: "A", sellerID: "1"},
{product: "B", sellerID: "2"},
{product: "C", sellerID: “2"},
{product: "E", sellerID: "1"},
{product: "F", sellerID: "3"}
```

Like google search, each domain is only displayed a maximum of 2 times in each results page. Each page will have 10 products and each sellerID will only be shown up to 2 of their products. Go to pages 2,3, ... the rules are still the same, that means an sellerID has 2 products displayed on page 1, then on page 2 they can still have 2 products displayed.

Comment: The closest thing that I could think of is Field Collapsing. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-collapse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be looking for top_hits agg. Please see my answer to this question: [ElasticSearch: query for N items of each category](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199512/elasticsearch-query-for-n-items-of-each-category/59200771#59200771)